# Query filtering data in mongo db

Tags: java, mongodb

I have a mongo db collection data set like this.

```
{
    "referenceId" : NumberLong(123),   
    "title" : "Title 1",
    "couseCallNo" : "[SCPI, BICO , HSJI]"
}
```

And in my **java** code I need to retrieve **this whole object** using the given **couseCallNo** . For example if I have **'SCPI'** as the coursecallNo I need to get the exact above object. Please help me out.

What I have done so far is

```
    QueryFilter filter = new QueryFilter();
    filter.addCriteria(Constants.Card.COURSE_CALL_NO,FilterOperator.EQUALS, courseCallNo);
    List<Course>  courseList =testRepository.find(filter);

    if(courseList != null && courseList.size()>0){
                    course =courseList.get(0);
```

testRepository is

```
MongodbEntityRepository<Course> testRepository;
```

Comment: are you using spring-data-mongodb or what libary is your QueryFilter from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `FilterOperator.ELEMENT_MATCH` to search elements of a subarray, as stated on MongoDB documentation:

> The $elemMatch operator matches documents in a collection that contain
>   an array field with at least one element that matches all the
>   specified query criteria.

source: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/

Your code should look like this:

```
 QueryFilter filter = new QueryFilter();
 filter.addCriteria(Constants.Card.COURSE_CALL_NO, FilterOperator.ELEMENT_MATCH, courseCallNo);
 List<Course>  courseList =testRepository.find(filter);

 if(courseList != null && courseList.size()>0){
     course =courseList.get(0); 
 }
```